# Sequentially Accessed Records in an Hierarchical (Object) DB

Tags: data-structures, sequential, object-oriented-database, zodb

I am creating an app that doesn't do any searching (or many other random-access activities). It's built on an object DB (ZODB if you're interested) and will store many instances of a identical type. Once they are created, the main access to objects in this structure will be a cron job working through them all sequentially at periodic intervals.

Is the best way to store them in an Object DB hierarchy simply placing them all 1 level below the hierarchy root? ZODB storage works very much like a python dictionary. On the (very) odd occasion they are accessed randomly, would this be a performance issue? I envisage that the max number of objects in the DB will be ~10k.

Answer (score 0):

Simply store them in a BTree (part of the ZODB package) and you should be fine; the BTree structures are highly efficient for sequential and random access.